# Tomcat - One host with 2 webapps

Tags: java, log4j, tomcat7, classloader

I'm working with tomcat 7 under Apache 2 and i need to have 2 webapp under the **same host** which is localhost e.g.

I worked with 2 webapps before but on different domains so i had different Host etc.

currently, I'm struggling with the log4j and noticed the following on tomcat start-up:

1. A.war deployed and i see the logs on A.log file
2. B.war deployed but i don't see the logs and sometimes i got the logs in **A.log instead of B.log**

When I'm programmatically loading the log4j in B.war like PropertyConfigurator.configure("") I'm starting to get logs on B.log but app A stop to write logs.
It looks like it used the same classloader and loads / changes the same log4j

Can you please advise what I'm doing wrong ? I know that each tomcat instance use one JVM but how can i be sure that each app using each one classloder ?

Comment: Each webapp is already running in its own classloader. You must be doing something very special to get it to misbehave like this. Where do you put the log4j jar? You should deploy it as part of each application and not put it in some common lib dir of the server.

Comment: Did you bundle log4j jars in your webapps?

Comment: I have the log4j.jar in the classpath in common place and not on each web application

Comment: The log4j.jar under the common path is used by more java application which can be also a standalone applications not web applications.

Comment: What is this common path? If it is common to tomcat then it will be in its classloader and initialized just once for container. Could you try to put log4j jars to each webapp? I want you to have two separate log4j setups.

Comment: Yes, going to try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run 2 webapps and add the configuration for both the webapps. Or you can have the single configuration and dd the multiple package in file.

For example

```
<appender name="services" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/shared_services.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{ISO8601} | %-5level | %thread | %logger{1} | %message%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <maxIndex>30</maxIndex>
        <fileNamePattern>services.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>

 <appender name="services1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/shared_services.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{ISO8601} | %-5level | %thread | %logger{1} | %message%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <maxIndex>30</maxIndex>
        <fileNamePattern>services1.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>


<root level="ALL">
    <appender-ref ref="test"/>
</root>

<logger name="org" level="INFO"/>

<logger name="org.apache.cxf.interceptor" level=""/>



 </configuration>
```

2 files is created in above example.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer but I'm not sure i understand it. Each web app have it's one log4j configuration, one is more complicated and different from the other so i want to be sure that the logs is going to the relevant place.